# Why are the scala docs missing methods?

Tags: scala, documentation

I have been trying to learn scala. One thing that I have noticed is the quality of the docs. They seem to miss out on a lot of methods. Is this intentional? I feel like I am missing something because they can't be this bad.

For example:

[Blog post on reading files with scala.](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-how-open-read-files-scala-examples)  The blog post recommends using a scala.io.Source.fromFile(..) method to read a file. It provides an iterator. Looks very nice to use. I want to get a better understanding of the class, so I go to the scala docs on [scala.io.Source](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.io.Source).

No where in the docs does it show the method for scala.io.Source.fromFile(..).  When I go to my IDE, it does try to autocomplete Source.fromFile(..), and it even works in the code.

This happened to me before when I was trying to use scala's database api. Am I missing something? Is there a secret button that pulls up this method? Have I gone my whole life being blind without realizing it? Or are the scaladocs really this bad?

Comment: Have to thumbs up, because this is such a paradigm shift that newbies should have to be confused about the module/class difference.  JavaDoc finally supports filtering on "static" methods. The UI for this should be no-brainer: given that the O/C icon is clever.

Comment: This is not a fault of the documentation, but of whatever resource you used to learn Scala. It should be blindingly obvious that `Source` cannot possibly be a class, because Scala is an object-oriented language and in an object-oriented language you call methods on objects, but in Scala, classes aren't objects, ergo if you can call a method on something, it cannot possibly be a class, it must be an object. And what do you know? If you look at the documentation of the `Source` object instead of the `Source` class, the documentation for `fromFile` is right there.

Comment: It is unclear on how to access the documentation for the object as opposed the class. All of the documentation links directly to classes. I did not realize that by clicking the header, the documentation page magically turns into the documentation for the object.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for (your favorite company)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fromFile` is not a method of *class* `Source`, it's a method of *object* `Source`. I.e. you can't write

```
val source: Source = ...
source.fromFile(...)
```

You are looking at the documentation for the class, which doesn't list the object's methods.
The link to the object's documentation is the circle with `C` near the class name at the top.